# which command to list all the files and folders in sda2

Tags: linux, command-line, webserver

I want to list all the files and folders in /dev/sda2 with their size and time stamp.

And I want to clear some unnecessary files from that disk..

Which commands to use to list all the files and folder? And which commands to use to remove unnecessary files?

Do I need to clear cache? What is the effect of clearing cache? what commands to use for clearing cache?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `df` output, `/dev/sda2` is `/` minus `/home`.

Personally for this I use `du`, and sort results on the size, so the last items are the biggest directories, and in the last items there are also the bigger individual files:

```
shopt -s extglob # possibly already done
cd /
du -ms ./!(home|proc|run|dev) | sort -n  # skip /home and others
```

If you want to go graphical, the `filelight` utility(*) can connect via your SSH connection (uses SFTP) to create a diagram of your server (click on any sector to get a detailed view of its contents). Can be a bit slow though.

(*) Initially on Linux, but IIRC there is a Windows version

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `tree` program. E.g. if you want to see the contents of `/dev/sda2`, you can use `tree -fiaPhD /dev/sda2`. (Adapted from solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168459)).

Explanation of the options:

- `-f` shows the full path
- `-i` hides the tree structure the program usually prints
- `-a` shows all files (and folders)
- `-P` selects the pattern to print
- `-h` shows the file in human readable (use `-s` for byte size)
- `-D` prints the last modification date

Be aware that folders will be displayed with 4.0K size.
Still, it's hard to give a general answer how to delete "unnecessary files" due to the difficult definition of unnecessary (unnecessary to whom? The system? The user?)